# Flask app not exposed properly on localhost

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a flask app, that i want to dockerize, so i have used the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine
WORKDIR /project
ADD . /project
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python","application.py"]
```

I built the container with a tag:
`docker build -t flask-sms-service:latest .`
and run it with the following command:
`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-sms-service`

I made sure to expose port 5000, for the server to be accessible. But when i access it on `127.0.0.1:5000` i can't access the container.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you used this piece of code

```
app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

flask run --host=0.0.0.0 This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.